# can I check if a number is odd or even by using add and subract instructions only?

Tags: c++

can I check if a number is even or odd by using add and subtraction. I can subtract the number until it get to 2 or 1 but can I do it without that. can i use the neighboring numbers to see if the number is odd or even

Thanks

Comment: If you want to subtract the number until you get 1 or 2, you'll probably need compare and jump instructions as well.

Comment: You can't do this without SOME other operation.

Comment: What comparison operators do you have? Really, the only smart way is using the binary AND operator.

Comment: Why can't you do more than add or subtract? Is this homework?

Comment: `x = x + x`, now you can tell that `x` is even.

Comment: @James you are right. I have the jump and compare instructions too. What I was trying to say was without using the modulo or division instructions.

Comment: Why do you want to do that with addition and/or subtraction? Checking whether the least significant bit is 1 or 0 is the common way of doing it.

Comment: Well, binary AND then. That's not modulo or division.

Comment: @Frustrated, I believe the use of "meta" tags, like "homework" are officially discouraged now...http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: When you say "can i use the neighboring numbers to see if the number is odd or even", what do you think "the neighboring numbers" means?

Comment: @Cpfohl: I think the "homework" tag serves a useful purpose.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, you're not specifying which operators you CAN use, but since you mentioned in one comment that you only really abhor division and modulo, I propose this:

```
if ((number & 1) == 0) {
    // even
} else {
    // odd
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack.

```
#include <assert.h>

// return i << 31 which is != 0 if i is odd
// 32-bit int implementations only;
// not portable, but could be made so -- you get the idea
int odd(int i) {
    assert((1<<31) != 0 && (1<<32) == 0);
    i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; 
    i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; 
    i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; 
    i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; i += i; 
    return i;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        assert(odd(i) ? (i&1) : !(i&1));
        ++i;
    } while (i != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other than that - hilarious approach. Totally didn't think about that. +1. Should clarify that this is specifically for 32-bit values.

Comment: Grr, daily limit reached. Remind me in an hour to give you an upvote :)

Comment: Sorry Jan. Didn't mean to bark at you. I was just surprised since you got a healthy amount of rep points, so I figured you're a pro by now! In any case - CTRL+K is your friend! Highlight the code and press CTRL+K - et voila!

Comment: Bad code. Section 6.5.7 of ISO C99 (which also applies to C++) says about the expression `(1<<32)`: "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." Many of the other expressions in your code also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Exceeding the value of a signed int is also undefined behavior. Of course it's bad code, but it's the only code here that really satisfies the condition of only using addition and subtraction (and comparing with 0). Btw, it's 4pm here, I can finally upvote!

Comment: Roland, thanks, yes, I know.  Just trying to write some quick code to explain the idea.  (I wrote a fair chunk of the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler back in the day.)

Answer (score 1):

This goes back to grade school actually.  Take the last digit.  If the last digit is odd, it's odd.  If the last digit is even it's even.  If you can look at the number in binary format it's even easier.

If you can't convert the number to any non-base 10 format then those are REALLY strange requirements - ie: homework.

Comment: how are you going to extract the last digit without modulo operation?

Comment: Who cares about base-10, just take the last one in base-2. :) Last bit extraction is `& 1`, see Mike's post.

Comment: @Russell, Yes, this sounds like some messed CS class homework.  I had some teachers that really knew their stuff and others that did not.  He is probably trying to teach something specific and that is fine.  Just looks weird when you have been writing code for years.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! You know that even and odd numbers always alternate, so start with 0 and a boolean variable set to true, and count up to your number, flipping a boolean each time you count!

Let's say n = 3

```
0 - even
1 - odd
2 - even
3 - odd
```

How you implement this is up to you, but you can even use recursion if you want (this example is in Java):

```
static boolean isOdd(int number){
    if(number > 0){
        return !isOdd(number-1);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work with negative numbers, but why do you even need to use addition and subtraction to check if a number is odd anyway? In the real world, you'd use modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer:

```
    int odd(int val){
        return ((val>>1)<<1) != 0;
    }
```